# monte carlo linear regression in r. Why is the slope lower than expected?

Tags: r, regression

Say I have two vectors with associated errors and I want to determine the uncertainty of slope of a linear regression using a simple monte carlo approach. I'm using the following code (suggestions for improvement welcome).

```
x <- seq(0.1, 10, by = 0.1)
y <- seq(1:100)

# uncertainty of x and y
sd.x <- 0.5
sd.y <- runif(100, 1, 5)


n <- 1000

# resample both x and y using sd.x and sd.y
xmc <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(x, function(x) rnorm(n = n, mean = x, sd = rep(sd.x, length(x))))))
ymc <- as.data.frame(t(mapply(function(x, y) rnorm(n = n, mean = x, sd = y), x = y, y = sd.y)))

res <- as.data.frame(t(mapply(function(x, y) lm(y~x)$coefficients, x = xmc, y = ymc)))
colnames(res) <- c('intercept', 'slope')

avg.slope <- mean(res$slope)
quant.slope <- quantile(res$slope, c(0.05, 0.95))
```

This is probably a trivial question, but I expect the average slope to be very close to 10 (with a small random deviation), but consistently get a value <10. What am I doing wrong, or do I not understand?

Comment: So you don't have a question about the code, but the statistical method? That's a question for [stats.se], not Stack Overflow. This site is for specific programming questions (which assume no advanced knowledge of statistics). If stats is required, give a sufficient description in the problem itself.

Comment: Well, I fear that I'm making a mistake in the code. That's why I posted it here.

Comment: It's not a mistake in your code. It's due to your understanding of linear regression. Set `sd.x <- 1000` and `sd.y <- runif(100, 1, 1000)`, then run your code again. Perhaps make some plots of one of your samples to see what is happening.

Comment: Study what happens as you decrease and increase the variability in the individual `x` and `y`.  You can do this with a simple thought experiment: (1) when you reduce the variability to zero, what must you obtain for the mean slopes? (2) when the variability is so great that the original values of `x` and `y` are so small they can be ignored, what do you expect the average slope to be?